# How is <class>::new a Runnable?

Tags: java, android, functional-programming

This is a contrived code example but based on a real world testing scenario from an Android project. It involves using class constructors to determine the validity of the class (ensure its in the correct state to be used). In this case just checking that the class constructor does not throw an exception before returning an instance of the class:

```
public class MyTestClass {

    private MyTestClass() {
       // Some code which might throw an exception
    }

    public static MyTestClass getInstance() {
       if (tryClassConstructor(MyTestClass::new)) {
          return new MyTestClass();
       }
       return null;
    }

    private static boolean tryClassConstructor(Runnable condition) {
       try {
           condition.run();
       } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```

I understand that getInstance() is passing a constructor method reference (MyTestClass::new) to its tryClassConstructor() method, but that method expects... a Runnable. So does this mean class default constructors are by default Runnable?

Comment: If the signature for a method/constructor matches the signature for `run`, it can be passed as a method reference.

Comment: Addendum to my original question: using ::new  as a Runnable can be hazardous to your runtime health in Android. Thanks to a colleague for pointing me to this article: https://vickychijwani.me/java-8-method-references/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following in a `Runnable`:

```
Runnable r = () -> {
  new MyTestClass();
};
```

Note that isn't returning the instance of `MyTestClass`: it's simply invoking the constructor, and discarding the instance.

That's all `MyTestClass::new` does when you use it as a `Runnable`.

You can do this because `MyTestClass::new` is *void-compatible*. `new MyTestClass()` is a statement expression, so it can stand by itself as a statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the ´Runnable´ is equivalent to

```
Runnable r = () -> new MyTestClass();
```

You can refer to [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for more information ("Reference to a Constructor").